# Sub containers in Flow

Tags: android, mortar, square-flow

Is there documentation on how to construct sub containers within flow?

For example, I have a Master, a Detail view.

I intend to add a popup view which will have it's own backstack. The popup will function as a wizard asking the user to complete some setup instruction and gets displayed as a popup.

Something like the layout below except there is a master container as well (fully displayed drawer layout)

[image]

How can this be achieved? Will the detail (or parent) container need to know about the existence of the popup container? Some thing like this?

```
@InjectView(R.id.master_container)
FramePathContainerView masterContainer;

@InjectView(R.id.detail_container)
FramePathContainerView detailContainer;

@InjectView(R.id.popup_container)
FramePathContainerView popupContainer;

@Override
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    return BackSupport.onBackPressed(popupContainer) 
            || BackSupport.onBackPressed(detailContainer);
}

@Override
public ViewGroup getCurrentChild() {
    Paths.MasterDetailPath showing = Path.get(getContext());
    return showing.isMaster() ? masterContainer.getCurrentChild()
            : showing.isPopup() ? popupContainer.getCurrentChild() 
            : detailContainer.getCurrentChild();
}
```

Is that what's supposed to be done? Thoughts?